# What is the best practice for jQuery Plugin Option sorting / nesting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What would be the best Way to sort (maybe nest) the options of a jQuery Plugin?
I've seen a lot of:

```
var defaults = {
    useOverlay : true,
    activeClass : "active",

    useAnimation : true,
    animationDuration : 400,
    animationEasing : "linear",

    addControls : true,
    showControlTitle : true,
    nextClass : "next",
    nextTitle : "Show Next",
    prevClass : "prev",
    prevTitle : "Show previous"
    //and so on
};
```

But wouldn't it be *better* to nest them?
Like so:

```
var defaults = {
    useOverlay : true,
    activeClass : "active",
    animation : {
      useAnimation : true,
      duration : 400,
      easing : "linear"
    },
    controls: {
      addControls : true,
      showTitle : true,
      next : {
        class : "next",
        title : "Show Next",
      },
      prev: {
        class : "prev",
        title : "Show previous",
      }
    }
    //and so on
};
```

Is there any Reason the Options of jQuery Plugins are mostly flat?

Comment: Developers are just lazy! It is just a personal preference of the one who's developing or writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a personal preference. I would take the second option as it is well described and basically neat. But, if you see the hurdles, you might need to use something like this for the class of the next button:

```
defaults.controls.next.class
```

Moreover, the names `next`, `class`, `defaults` are reserved words (I am just saying there are a lot of reserved words, that might get into conflict). So, having something like `next_class`, `animation_use`, etc. will make sure we don't mess up with JavaScript's reserved keywords.

Also as I said in the comments, most of the developers (including me) are lazy as anything, and they just want to create a variable, no matter if they have a structure or not. This would avoid thinking long in deciding on the structure.

Ultimately, it is just a personal choice.